# separate return statement from other statements ANTRL

Tags: antlr

here's part from my grammar.

```
statement
    :   assignmentStatement
    |       doLoopStatement 
    |   whileStatement
    |   ifStatement
    |   procedureCallStatement
    ;


function 
    : 'FUNCTION' IDENT '(' parameters? ')' ':' type ':=' 
         (variable (';' variable)*)?
        'BEGIN'
            main_body  //body can be empty
            return_Statement 
        'END' IDENT
    ;
```

where main_body is:

```
main_body
    : (statement (';' statement)*)?
    ;
```

now, before creating my AST, I need to fix the return statement,

the problem is that the `assignmentStatement` and `return_Statement` 
and so I'm getting a LL(*) error from the parser, as it does not know what to choose.

```
assignmentStatement
    :   IDENT ':=' expression
    ;

return_Statement
    :   IDENT ':=' expression
    ;
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If `assignmentStatement` is really supposed to be identical to `return_Statement` then there's no reason to have both. Eliminate the `return_Statement` rule and in your `function` rule replace it with `assignmentStatement`.